# Combinatorics: binomial coefficient with negative fractions

Tags: combinatorics

We've been asked to prove an identity using binomial coefficients, but there's a negative fraction involved and I'm not sure what to do.

Prove that $${-1/2 \choose n} = (-1/4)^n {2n \choose n}$$  I tried to do it the way you would if it was positive (expanding using ${n \choose k} =(n(n-1)(n-2)...(n-k+1))/n!)$ and multiplying by (1/2)/(1/2) and I got the $(-1/4)^n$ but I couldn't write what remained as ${2n \choose n}$

Answer (score 3):

$$\binom{n}{k} = \frac{n!}{k! \, (n-k)!} = \prod_{m=1}^k \frac{n-m+1}{m}.$$ So for $n = -1/2$, we have $$\begin{align*} \binom{-{\textstyle \frac{1}{2}}}{k} &= \prod_{m=1}^k \frac{\frac{1}{2} - m}{m} = \prod_{m=1}^k \frac{1 - 2m}{2m} = \prod_{m=1}^k \frac{(1 - 2m)(2m)}{4m^2} \\ &= \prod_{m=1}^k \frac{(2m-1)(2m)}{-4m^2} = (-4)^{-k} \frac{(2k)!}{k! \, k!} = (-4)^{-k} \binom{2k}{k}. \end{align*}$$

Answer (score 2):

Yes, the idea is correct. But please change the variables to avoid double use (of $n$ in your case),

$$\binom{α}{n}=\frac{α(α-1)...(α-n+1)}{n!}=(-1)^n\frac{(n-1-α)(n-2-α)...(1-α)α}{n!}$$

Now use that with $α=-\frac12$ you have $k-α=\frac12(2k+1)$ and $k=\frac12(2k)$ to fill the gaps between these odd numbers.

Comment: So I did as you suggested and I got \binom{-1/2}{n}=(-1)^n\frac{((1/2)(2n+1)-1)((1/2)(2n+2)-2)...(1+(1/2))(-1/2)}{n!}

Comment: Sorry about the previous post. So I did as you suggested and I got $$\binom{-1/2}{n}=(-1)^n\frac{((1/2)(2n+1)-1)((1/2)(2n+1)-2)...(1+(1/2))(-1/2)}{n!}$$ Where do you suggest I substitute the $k=\frac12(2k)$ ? Also I want to take out the 1/2 as common in the numerator but that affects the remaining (-1) (-2) in the bracket which I want the to stay the same so that I get (2n)(2n-1)... What am I missing?

Comment: Use the other answers too. In the first step you get that the numerator has all the odd numbers from $1$ to $2n-1$. If you fill the gaps with the even numbers from $2$ to $2n$ you have to compensate in the denominator with $n!$ and $2^n$.

Comment: Thanks I think I've got it now.