# References on binomial coefficients of the form $\binom{-1/m}{k} $

Tags: combinatorics, reference-request, binomial-coefficients, gamma-function

I'm interested in binomial coefficients of the form $$\binom{-1/m}{k} .$$
Although I have found some [sources](https://brilliant.org/wiki/fractional-binomial-theorem/) indicating this expression can be rewritten in an interesting way when $m=2$, I have found little information so far on it when $m \in \mathbb{Z}_{\geq 3}$.

I am therefore curious as to whether any articles or book chapters on this particular binomial expression have been written. Information regarding sums involving this expression is also much appreciated.

Comment: +1 Interesting query, very nicely presented.

Comment: Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/688276/combinatorics-binomial-coefficient-with-negative-fractions

Comment: @Äres Indeed. I've also referenced that question in another question of mine on this topic: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3850064/is-there-a-closed-form-for-the-binomial-expression-binom-1-mk

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Consider the formal power series $y(x)$ satisfying $y^m = \frac{1}{1 - mx}$, which gives

$$y(x) = (1 - mx)^{- \frac 1 m} = \sum_{n \ge 0} (-1)^n m^n {-\frac 1 m \choose n} x^n.$$

Taking logs and exponentiating again gives

$$y(x) = \exp \left( \frac{1}{m} \log \frac{1}{1 - mx} \right) = \exp \left( \sum_{k \ge 1} \frac{m^{n-1} x^n}{n} \right).$$

This gives us that $n! [x^n] y(x)$ counts permutations but where a permutation with cycles of length $\ell_1, \dots \ell_n$ is weighted by $m^{\sum (\ell_i - 1)}$. The quantity $\sum (\ell_i - 1)$ is sometimes called the **length** of a permutation; it gives the minimal $\ell$ such that a permutation can be expressed as a product of $\ell$ transpositions. It's equal to $n$ minus the number of cycles, which means we get the [Stirling numbers of the first kind](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling_numbers_of_the_first_kind) but in reverse order:

$$\boxed{ (-1)^n m^n {-\frac 1 m \choose n} = \frac{1}{n!} \sum_{i=0}^n \left[ {n \atop i} \right] m^{n-i} }.$$

Compare to the generating function for the Stirling numbers in the usual order, which is

$$(-1)^n {-m \choose n} = {n+m-1 \choose n} = \frac{1}{n!} \sum_{i=0}^n \left[ {n \atop i} \right] m^i$$

and which corresponds to looking at $(1 - x)^{-m}$.

---

What you might've been hoping for was an expression in terms of ${mn \choose n}$ generalizing the case $m = 2$, and it turns out that some nice things can be said about this sequence. Using [Lagrange inversion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange_inversion_theorem) or the more explicit combinatorial argument in [this blog post](https://qchu.wordpress.com/2010/10/08/update-and-the-combinatorics-of-quintic-equations/) we can show that the formal power series $z(x)$ satisfying $z = 1 + xz^m$ has coefficients

$$z(x) = \sum_{n \ge 0} \frac{1}{(m-1)n + 1} {mn \choose n} x^n$$

which generalizes the well-known generating function for the Catalan numbers, to which it reduces when $m = 2$ (and in fact these coefficients count $m$-ary trees in a way that generalizes the way the Catalan numbers count binary trees). This is Example 6.2.6 in Stanley's [*Enumerative Combinatorics, Vol. II*](http://www-math.mit.edu/~rstan/ec/). Example 6.2.7 uses this to show that the formal power series $w(x) = \sum_{n \ge 0} {mn \choose n} x^n$ satisfies

$$\frac{w - 1}{1 + (m-1)w} = x \left( \frac{mw}{1 + (m-1)w} \right)^m$$

so like $y$ and $z$ it is also algebraic, but its minimal polynomial appears to be more complicated. For example, setting $m = 3$ and clearing denominators gives that $w = \sum_{n \ge 0} {3n \choose n} x^n$ satisfies

$$(w - 1)(1 + 2w)^2 = 27x w^3$$

and expanding and rearranging gives

$$(27x - 4) w^3 + 3w + 1 = 0.$$

So more complicated than $(1 - 3x) y^3 = 1$, unfortunately. Stanley is probably your best bet for learning more about this sort of thing; it's extremely comprehensive, especially the exercises. The series $w$ appears again in Exercise 6.13.

Comment: Thank you! I did not expect the connection with the Stirling numbers of the first kind.

Comment: do you perhaps know whether similar identities exist for $\binom{m-1/m}{k} $ ?

Comment: @Max: you can try the same style of argument for something like $(1 - mx)^{m - \frac 1 m}$ and see what you get. I don't think it's anything particularly nice.

Comment: Alright, I will try that just to make sure. I'm asking about this mainly to gain a better understanding of the following questions. If you have any ideas, I'd be interested in reading about them: (1) https://mathoverflow.net/questions/373499/a-question-on-an-identity-relating-certain-sums-of-harmonic-numbers , (2) https://mathoverflow.net/questions/373231/what-is-known-about-sums-of-the-form-sum-n-2-infty-zetan-1p

Comment: I'm sorry to come back to this yet again, but I have to ask: do you know whether the boxed identity appears somewhere in the literature?

Comment: @Max: it is arguably a very trivial consequence of the usual identity involving the Stirling numbers in the usual order. In general if $P(x)$ is a polynomial of degree $n$ then $x^n P(1/x)$ reverses its coefficients.

Comment: very interesting indeed !

Answer (score 1):

A simple identity:

$${(1+x)^{1/m}}=\sum_{k\geq 0}{\binom{1/m}{k}}x^k.$$

converting it to the binomial  form $$\binom{km}{k}$$ is far harder though

For m=3, it arises when finding the roots of a cubic equation [1] and certain enumerative combinatorics problems in which the characteristic equation is a cubic  , such as random walks involving two steps forward and one step back. The 1 step forward, one step back process involves the usual m=2, but m=3  case is far harder and nice analytic expressions as far as I know do not exist ,except for simple cases in which there is a single absorbing barrier.

see:

[1] [Find the second real root for cubic $x^3+1-x/b=0$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4224731/find-the-second-real-root-for-cubic-x31-x-b-0)